# Store SSH command history on local machine

Tags: ssh, shell, command-history

I often use SSH to connect to ARM machine which reboots regularly and doesn't have any persistent memory to store `sh` command history. Is there a way to store such history on my local machine so it could be accessible by `^R` and `up`/`down` when connected to the remote? Or is there another workaround to such problem besides storing most useful commands in a notepad? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formally answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/422478/store-ssh-command-history-on-local-machine) on Unix SE:

> [rlwrap](https://github.com/hanslub42/rlwrap) utility uses the GNU readline library to front-end any command with a re-usable history that is saved by default in a file `~/.`*command*`_history`.